# SignalR .Net Core - A server to client call that results in long running (but async) processing on the client blocks further client calls

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, signalr

.Net 6

I am making a call from the server to the client thru signalr
The processing on the client is long running (minutes!), but async (ie method is async Task), and is specified in the On call, eg

`On("Something", HandleSomething)`
where

```
private async Task HandleSOmething()
{
:
    something that takes a long time
:
}
```

but it blocks any other calls to this client from the server (or maybe others - haven't tested).

I have "fixed" this by ensuring that I return immediately from the processing rather than awaiting, and this has fixed it.

Note that when the processing did complete and the call returned (back to the server), then the missed messages where received so must have been queued.

I haven't seen any guidance regarding this, or mention of it anywhere.
It seems a danger that any client could cause "damage" to itself so easily.

I see that for client to server messages there is an option to set the number of simultaneous messages allowed, but I couldnt see anything from server to client.

Comment: Is this answer your problem? https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10257   Please provide a lot more information about what you're trying to do - in particular, what project type you're using. 
If you can provide a minimal reproducible example, including both the C# code and the project file, 
we're much more likely to be able to help you.

Comment: Not quite, as that mostly talks about client to server requests, whereas my issue is with server to client requests.  They are definitely related tho.

It does imply this is currently expected behaviour, which they hope to fix sometime.